# Cargo add `Command failed due to unhandled error: reference 'refs/remotes/origin/master' not found`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am getting

```
Command failed due to unhandled error: reference 'refs/remotes/origin/master' not found; 
class=Reference (4); code=NotFound (-3)
```

when trying a cargo add.

I've removed `~/.cargo/registry` and reinstalled via rustup but no luck. It's thrown when I do a `cargo add flexbuffers` but it's not limited to just that package - it doesn't work for others e.g. serde.

Comment: There's an issue on the Github page about this specific error: https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit/issues/411

Comment: Googling didn't find that for me - thanks. It seems that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to:

```
mv ~/.cargo/registry/index/github.com-*/.git/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD \
   ~/.cargo/registry/index/github.com-*/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master
```

because of [this issue](https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit/issues/411).